# Find the cardinality of sets (linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Find the cardinality of these sets:

1. |{B ⊂ Z5 x Z5 x Z5 x Z5: B - base of a vector space}|
2. |{f: Z5 x Z5 x Z5 → Z5 x Z5 x Z5: f - linear function, which is also injective}|
3. |{f:Z5 x Z5 x Z5 → Z5 x Z5 x Z5: f - linear function and dim(ker(f)) = 1 }|

By writing Z5, I mean ({0,1,2,3,4}, + modulo 5, * modulo 5)

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hint for the first: Try making an ordered basis.  For your first choice, are there any vectors you shouldn't pick?  How many?  Once having chosen your first vector and moving on to choose your second, are there any vectors you shouldn't pick?  How many?  Continue in this fashion and then if you were wanting to count unordered bases, divide by $4!$ to unorder them.

Comment: For (2), the question can be solved almost identically to (1).  Pick what $f(e_1)$ maps to... pick what $f(e_2)$ maps to, and then what $f(e_3)$ maps to... noting that each must map to linearly independent vectors.  For (3), again, very similar... except here the first step is picking what vector it is in the domain that generates the kernel, and then using some predefined method, extending to a basis of the domain that includes that vector and choosing two linearly independent vectors for your second and third basis elements to map to.

Comment: In the first problem I was thinking about: 
Let v \in Z5^5 and v = (a,b,c,d). The I can split v as follows: a*(1,0,0,0) + b*(0,1,0,0) + c*(0,0,1,0) + d*(0,0,0,1). So now I have one of the bases: B = {(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,1,0), (0,0,0,1)}. Cardinality of B is 4 and the other bases have the same cardinality as B. Now I have to find the other basis. I was thinking to generate them using B, but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (1):

Begin by simplifying the problem by having us count ordered bases.

Pick the first basis vector.  It can be any of the $5^4=625$ elements in $(\Bbb Z_5)^4$ except for the zero vector, so we have $624$ choices available here.  Call our first basis vector $a$.

Whichever element was chosen as the first basis vector, we move on to pick our next basis vector, but it must be taken from from $(\Bbb Z_5)^4\setminus \text{span}(a)$.  There are five elements in the span of $a$ and so there are $625-5=620$ vectors to choose from for our second basis vector.  Call this second choice $b$.

Continuing, whichever element was chosen as the second basis vector we will be able to pick any vector as our third except for one in $\text{span}(a,b)$ and so we now have $25$ vectors we are not allowed to choose from, leaving $625-25=600$ choices.

Continue in this fashion until we have selected all four of our basis vectors.  Applying the rule of product, we have a total of $624\cdot 620\cdot 600\cdot 500$ different ordered selections possible.

If we wanted to have counted unordered selections, correct our count by dividing by $4!$

---

For (2) and (3), the procedure is similar.

> (2):  $124\cdot 120\cdot 100$

$~$

> (3): $124\cdot 124\cdot 120$